# Reversing array without using any method (reversed, append, etc)

Tags: swift

There is a method .reversed(), but what i've been trying to do is to reverse an array WITHOUT USING ANY METHODS AT ALL (**.append**, **.count**, .dropLast etc)

In my code I am using append-method, but I'd like to get rid of it

Could someone explain me? I am trying to understand how methods actually work

```
func reverseArray(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var length = 0
    var array2: [Int] = []

    for _ in array {
        length += 1
    }
    while length>0 {
        array2.append(array[length - 1])
        length = length - 1
    }

    return array2
}

var sequence = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
reverseArray(array:sequence)
```

Comment: You can't write the code without using any methods. Code such as `array[length - 1]` is actually making a method call to get the value at a specific index in the array.

Comment: Array store's its own count, so it can be accessed quickly, without needing to iterate all elements. Besides, it has to know the count so that it can know where the end is, so it can stop iteration at the end. `count` isn't a method, it's a computed proprety.

Comment: Your `length` calculation is technically correct, but the `for` calls methods: one call to `Array.makeIterator()`, and `n + 1` calls to `IndexingIterator.next()`.

Comment: Not related to your question but it would be easier to decrease length before subscripting the array `length -= 1` and then `array2.append(array[length])` or as suggested by John `array2 += [array[length]]`
`

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of _all_ method calls, or just the _appearance_ of method calls?  Because the former is not possible, unless you reimplement `Array` entirely in one method.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure *why* you would want to do this, but to solve your specific question, you could wrap the value in a second array and then replace `append` with concatenation:

```
array2 += [array[length - 1]]
```